# FastCGI sending image data as response C++

Tags: html, c++, image, cgi

The application I'm working on needs to be able to send images as a response. I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work properly. I tried making a response message string with "Content type images/jpeg" after making a simple get request, and what pops up in the browser is a broken image symbol, so I guess it knows it's supposed to be an image. My images are stored in the database as hexidecimal. How do I format the response for the FCGXFPrintF(...) message to make an image pop up. I tried

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n
<a bunch of hexidecimal>
```

but that doesn't work. Can someone give me an example of how to format the message, and an example of actual image data for me to test (because my image data might be broken)

Thanks

Comment: I presume you realise you have missed the colon and two linefeeds.

Comment: yeah, guess it was bad to assume people would assume I have it correct in my code. Fixed

Comment: Maybe show your code so folks can see what you have so far...

Comment: the code in the post is what I have. Which is just a string which I output as the response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an image called `image.jpg`, paste this into a file called `go`, then type

```
php -f go
```

and you will see what your C++ should generate:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile('image.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: I can not save the image data as an actual jpg file anywhere. I need to be able to get the hexidecimal from the database and given that data, make an image pop up. I was hoping I could just put the hexidecimal data in the response (I know it'sjpeg)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you do this on your server - I meant to just run it on your development PC to see how the correct output looks.

Comment: I got you. I don't have an 'image.jpg' file, just the data for that file, which I can't store outside of the database, so I wouldn't know how to translate that readfile(...) line into something for my case. Am I just pasting the hex into go?